# How can I add list text to a matplotlib polar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13, 13))
ax1 = plt.subplot( projection='polar') 
ax1.set_theta_zero_location('N') 
ax1.set_thetagrids(np.arange(0.0, 360.0, 25.7143))# /14
ax1.set_rgrids(np.arange(0.8,1,))


amount1 = [('89','c'),'04','76',('93','a'),'56',
          '11','45','61','85',('37','b'),
          '51','97','24','07']
r = 0.8
#theta = 25.7143 * range(14) # amount1:add to intersections


plt.show()
```

[image]

chart make in photoshop.
I am a newbie with python.
I am a foreigner, and my question is expressed through code and graphics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the angles for `set_thetagrids`, you can use `np.linspace` from `0` to `360` with `14` steps but with `endpoint=False`.

The angles for the placement are in radians; `np.radians(thetas)` converts them. To place the texts, you can loop through `amount1`. A little circle can be positioned e.g. via `ax1.scatter(x, y, ...)` with a given interior and edge color.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13, 13))
ax1 = plt.subplot(projection='polar')
ax1.set_theta_zero_location('N')
thetas = np.linspace(0, 360, 14, endpoint=False)
ax1.set_thetagrids(thetas)
ax1.set_rgrids([0.8, 1], [])
ax1.set_ylim(0, 1)

amount1 = [('89', 'c'), '04', '76', ('93', 'a'), '56', '11', '45', '61', '85', ('37', 'b'), '51', '97', '24', '07']
r = 0.8
for am1, theta in zip(amount1, np.radians(thetas)):
    color = 'white'
    if type(am1) is tuple:
        color = {'a': 'turquoise', 'b': 'orchid', 'c': 'lightcoral'}[am1[1]]
        am1 = am1[0]
    ax1.text(theta, r, am1, color='firebrick', ha='center', va='center')
    ax1.scatter(theta, r, s=500, marker='o', color=color, edgecolor='red', alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image: polar plot]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Include a color for all of the labels.

```
amount1 = [('89','g'),('04','k'),('76','k'),('93','r'),('56','k'),
          ('11','k'),('45','k'),('61','k'),('85','k'),('37','b'),
          ('51','k'),('97','k'),('24','k'),('07','k')]
```

You can specify the text coordinates in (theta, r) coordinates.  The angle should be in radians

```
theta = 2*pi/14
for i in range(14):
    ax1.text(theta*i,0.8,amount1[i][0],color=amount[i][1],fontsize=24)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!